# what is the best way to edit similar strings?

Tags: vim

I need to make next task:

file:

```
string1 data1 data
```

I need to create more strings with only changes in digits

```
string2 data2 data
string3 data3 data
string4 data4 data
```

How can i do it fast ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

select that input line, yank it into buffer a: `"ayy`.

Then record the following sequence: `qq`

1. `"ap` Paste the line below
2. `ctrl-a` Increment the digit
3. `w` Move forward one word
4. `ctrl-a` Increment the digit
5. `"ayy` Yank this line in as your new baseline

End your macro with `q`

Then repeat it as many times as you need (let's say 42), with `42@q`

Answer (score 3):

Several plugins manage that: [visincr.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=670), increment.vim.

I use visincr and that is very easy: Visual block, `:I`.

Comment: im using vim plugins when they are only necessary and there is no simple way to implement it.